# using mongorestore for a db present in my computer

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I just started using mongodb so my question might be a little basic.
I have a folder with the collections I want to restore(this was a zip file I downloaded from my email).
How do I use mongorestore to restore this db into my local db?

Answer (score 0):

How about reading then [manual.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) 
Simples form of that command is `mongorestore  directory/` where mongod is running localhost at port 27017 and that 'directory' have those dump files.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve it.